# Can we use table to echo data called by two different queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am selecting `user_id` from table `follow` and then calling data from other table `members` matching that `user_id` but when I echo out It shows only one member with least `user_id`. So I thought displaying members in table may help and now my code is like this:

```
$following =$db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM follow WHERE uid_fk=:userid order by user_id");
$following->execute(array(':userid'=>$userid));
$row = $following->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user_id = $row['user_id'];

$check =$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE userid=:user_id");
$check->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
$row = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
<table>
<tr>
<?php do { ?>
 <td>
  <div><p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p></div>
  <div><p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p></div>
  <div><p><?php echo $row['about']; ?></p></div>
  <div style="height:20px;"></div>
 </td>
<?php
$row = $following->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!isset($nested_List)) {
$nested_List= 1;
}
if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && $nested_List++%2==0) {
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
} while ($row); 
?>
</table>
```

As you can see my table is only for `$following` and so now it displays all members `$user_id` in table but how to add second query to table code i.e, `$check` so that I can also echo out info about members in table. I don't want to store member info in follow table any other way to do that?

Comment: You can reduce those two statements to a single one by means of a JOIN on sql level. That way you can stay with your simple iteration over the result set you get. Otherwise you would have to execute the second statement again and again for each result from the first statement.

Comment: thanks `$sql = "SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN follow ON follow.user_id=members.userid ORDER BY userid ";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` tried this thing but failed

Comment: And "but failed" does mean _what_ exactly? Sorry, but we do not have your tables, so we cannot really comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was omitting `where` attribute so this is how we could call data from two tables and show the result in table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN follow ON follow.user_id=members.userid where user_id=$userid ORDER BY userid "; $query = $db->prepare($sql);     
$query->execute(); 
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
<table>
<tr>
<?php do { ?>
<td>
<div><p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p></div>
<div><p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p></div>
<div><p><?php echo $row['about']; ?></p></div>
<div style="height:20px;"></div>
</td>
<?php
$row = $following->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!isset($nested_List)) {
$nested_List= 1;
}
if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && $nested_List++%2==0) {
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
} while ($row); 
?>
</table>
```